# Icons for privilege not visible on mobile site/app

Tags: bug, android-app, mobile-web

Icons for privilege are not visible on mobile site as well as mobile app  (on Android).

#### Android app

> [image: mobile app]

#### Mobile website

> [image: mobile site]