# Privilege icon is missing if viewing the achievements dialog from stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, achievements-dialog

When viewing the achievements dialog from any site other than **stackexchange.com** the privilege icon is displaying.

[image: MSE]

But when I viewing the achievements dialog from **stackexchange.com** the privilege icon is not displaying.

[image: SE]

This question is not the [duplicate of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260082), since the existing question is mention about the mobile view/mobile app. The current post is about the issue with the stackexchange.com in the desktop view alone.